# Loop Until a Connection is Made With fopen() in PHP

Tags: php

When running my script which opens a CSV file with `fopen()`, it will uncommonly fail to load with the following error:

`Warning: fopen(https://www.link.com/csv.csv): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable in C:\xampp\htdocs\create_products.php on line 28`

My code is below:

```
$csv = array();
$line = array();
if (FALSE !== $handle = fopen("https://www.fmasarovic.com/export_feed.php?preset=poshbag_boutique", "r")) {
    while (FALSE !== $row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        $csv[] = $row;
    }
}
foreach (array_slice($csv, 1) as $row) {
    $new_row = array();
    for ($i = 0, $c = count($csv[0]); $i < $c; ++$i) {
        $new_row[$csv[0][$i]] = $row[$i]; 
    }
    $line[] = $new_row;
}
```

I put this error down to server issues and I can accept that this can happen sometimes, so what I would like to know is whether it's possible to put the first line of code in a loop which will carry on attempting to connect until a successful connection is made and if so, which direction I would need to go in?

This is important because I will be setting a cron job to every 2 hours so I don't want there to be a gap of 4 hours between script runs when this error occurs.

Thank you very much for your time in advance.

Comment: make a `while ('iHaveNoConnection') ` loop and insert a little sleep inside. And a counter...to stop after some attempts.

Comment: Don't use `while (FALSE !== ...)`. Just write `while ($row = fgetcsv($handle))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `while()` loop that repeats `fopen()` when the connection fails.

```
while (!($handle = fopen("https://www.fmasarovic.com/export_feed.php?preset=poshbag_boutique", "r"))) {
    sleep(1); // So we don't hammer the website continuously
}
while ($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    $csv[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.